# Determine if there is a matching value in specified range

Tags: excel, vba, countif

I have 200 data entry rows. I need to know if the current cell value (example B6) matches any above values in column B (example B1:B4). If so place "x" in the current row on column d.

Current formula `=IF(COUNTIF($B$5:B35,B36)>0,"x","")`

Comment: What is your question? You described a scenario and posted the formula you use to calculate it. Also note that VB and VBA are not the same. Decide what you want to use. If you are writing code, please post your code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: Welcome! It will be helpful if you edit this question to include: 1. some sample data that you're working against, including column headers; 2. an example of what ouptut you were hoping to see; and 3. what you actually got.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you need help with the formula per se or with writing an equivalent VBA function that performs the same functionality. Therefore, I am sharing both options:

**Using Excel's COUNTIF**

Let us assume that your data starts at cell A1 and has a header row. Then, you would have to ...

- ... place a formula somewhat similar to the one you already have,`=IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2, B2) > 1, "x", "")` in cell D2
- ... copy the formula in D2 down the cells in column D until you reach the last row of data

The reason for using "B$2:B**36**" and "> **1**",  in row 36, for example, (as opposed to "B$2:B**35**" and "> **0**", the way you had it) is that it allows you to have the formula in all the rows after the header row. Otherwise, you would have to leave D2 with no formula and add the first formula in D3.

The reason for the "$" in "B$2:B2" is that it forces the formula to always search from the top of the table, no matter what row you copy the formula to.

The formulas would look something like this:

[Image of sample sheet with COUNTIF formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caslx.png)

---

**Using VBA**

If you want to use a VBA function instead of Excel's `COUNTIF` (to hopefully get a faster result), you could create a function such as this:

```
Function ValueRepeats(ByVal valuesRange As Range)
  Const headerRow = 1 'If there is no header, you can use 0 instead of 1

  'Assume that the value will repeat itself
  ValueRepeats = True

  Dim values As Variant: values = valuesRange.Value

  'If [values] is not an array, it is a single value, meaning that it cannot have a duplicate
  If Not IsArray(values) Then
    ValueRepeats = False
    Exit Function
  End If

  'Get the 2-dimensional array's bounds
  Dim arrLb As Long: arrLb = LBound(values, 1)
  Dim arrUb As Long: arrUb = UBound(values, 1)
  Dim index2 As Long: index2 = LBound(values, 2) 'In the 2nd dimension, we only
                                                 '  care about the first column

  'Get the value to search for (the last value in the array)
  Dim lastValue As Variant: lastValue = values(arrUb, index2)

  'Traverse the array and compare the elements against the last value
  Dim i As Long
  For i = arrLb To arrUb - 1
    If ValuesMatch(lastValue, values(i, index2)) Then Exit Function
  Next

  ValueRepeats = False 'If we are here, no repeat value was found
End Function

Private Function ValuesMatch(ByVal v1 As Variant, ByVal v2 As Variant)
  'NOTE: This function treats the string "5" and the number 5 as different values;
  '  also, string comparisons are case-insensitive,
  '  and Null, Empty, and "" are considered equivalent; all of this can be changed as needed

  Dim typ1 As Integer: typ1 = VarType(v1)

  'Make sure the values are of the same type (to avoid confusing numbers and dates),
  '  unless the values can be converted to an empty string
  If typ1 <> VarType(v2) Then
    ValuesMatch = (v1 & "") = (v2 & "") 'Null, Empty, and "" will match each other
    Exit Function
  End If

  Select Case typ1
    Case vbNull
      ValuesMatch = True 'v1=v2 does not work if both values are null
    Case vbString
      ValuesMatch = StrComp(v1, v2, vbTextCompare) 'Case-insensitive string comparison
    Case Else
      ValuesMatch = v1 = v2
  End Select
End Function
```

You would then use the formula "`=IF(ValueRepeats(B$2:B2), "x", "")`" in D2 (instead of the `COUNTIF` formula) and copy that formula down the rest of column D. The formulas would look something like this:

[image: Image of sample sheet with VBA formulas]

The only advantage I see in using a VBA function is that it allows you to abort the search after the first duplicate is found. `COUNTIF`, by contrast, counts all the duplicates, even if you do not need to know that number.

---

**Using INDEX/MATCH (a third alternative)**

To avoid using VBA and to avoid counting all duplicates with `COUNTIF`, you can use a formula that utilises Excel's `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions.

In that case, you would have to leave D2 blank with no formula, and then add a formula such as the following in D3:

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(B$2:B2, MATCH(B3, B$2:B2, 0),1)), "", "x")
```

You would then have to copy this formula down the rest of column D. The formulas would look something like this:

[Image of sample sheet with INDEX/MATCH formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RU0W.png)

To better understand INDEX and MATCH, I would recommend a page such as the following:

[ExcelJet.Net page explaining INDEX/MATCH](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match)

---